# Number of words in mumbo-jumbo tribe's language

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

A tribe named Mumbo-Jumbo has $3$ letters in their alphabet, how many words are there with length no greater than $4$? I answered $3^4+3^3+3^2+3^1$. The author's answer is $40$, did the author add up $3^3+3^2+3^1+3^0$ by accident?

Comment: Your answer is fine. The book is wrong.

Comment: Well, I suppose you could call the empty word a word if you want to.  But there are $3^4=81$ words of length exactly $4$ and they certainly count.

Comment: There 40 possible words to jumbo of lenght less than 4 including the sound of silence  minus all the tongue tieing jumboes that don't mumbo.